# Create button to update in django posts with javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, python, django, fetch, posts

I have an html that displays user's posts. At the same time, the post model is accessible via fetch (javascript). I want to create a button to update the content of the posts that django shows but with the fetch. The problem is that when the button is created in my code, instead of creating a button for each post, it creates 5 update buttons in the first post and it is logical because that is the id that I give it. How can I add a button to each of the posts that django shows with javascript?
Note: the project its a test for the real project.[image]

I want to add a update button with javascritp in a django posts for update a field

My html:

```
<div id="formulario" class="form-style" style="border: 5px solid rgb(255, 170, 0);">
        <h1>User's Posts</h1>
        {% for post in object_list %}
        <div id="posts-div" style="border: 5px solid red;">
            <h3 id="user">{{post.usuario}} -  User with id: {{post.id}}</h3>
            <h3>{{post.contenido}} - {{post.id}}</h3>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <h1>Agregar</h1>
        <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Save">
        </form>

    </div>
```

My views.py

```
class PostsViewSet (viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Posts.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostsSerializer


class PostView(CreateView, ListView):
    model = Posts
    fields = ['contenido','edad','usuario']
    template_name = 'api_app/posts.html'
    success_url ='.'
```

My serializer.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Posts



class PostsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Posts
        fields = ['usuario', 'edad', 'contenido']
```

My javascript:

```
addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {     
        fetch('/api/posts')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            data.forEach(post => {

                console.log(post.usuario)

                post_div = document.getElementById('posts-div'); 
                update_post = document.createElement('button');
                update_post.innerHTML = 'Update';
                post_div.appendChild(update_post);
                
            });
            
                
        });
      
        });
```

I know the api not specify the method but first i have attemp to create the button in every post

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem in this way. So far (before testing it much) it has worked. The difference is the querySelectorAll the variable i and the i++

data.forEach(post => {

```
            console.log(post.usuario);
            
            post_div = document.querySelectorAll('.post-div-class')[i]; 
            update_post = document.createElement('button');
            update_post.innerHTML = 'Update';
            post_div.appendChild(update_post);
            ++i;
            console.log(i);
            
        });
```